# Exclude specific elements from XML using XPath or XSLT

Tags: c#, xslt, xpath

Consider the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>

<book category="cooking">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <price>30.00</price>
  <contents>jjjadLKjlkdasndlakjd...</contents>
</book>

<book category="children">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="web" cover="paperback">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <price>39.95</price>
  <contents>jjjadLKjlkdasndlakjd...</contents>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

Goal is to exclude the "contents" element and get the resulting XML AS-IS.

I tried axes and other operators. However, it doesn't seem possible to achieve this using XPath. Please correct me if I'm wrong about it.

If XPath solultion is not possible can the following XSLT work?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>

  <!-- For each element, create a new element with the same local-name (no namespace) -->
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/> 
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::company)]"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: XPath can only select elements from the source document, it can't modify them in any way (e.g. by removing some children)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the second template of your XSLT to an empty template:

```
<xsl:template match="contents" />
```

Also, if you wanted to keep the namespace (to keep the rest of your XML "AS-IS"), you could simply use the identity template:

```
<!-- identity template -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. Just a thought, the "content" element here is a 3 to 4 MB PDF document in base 64 string format. One can use regex to select desired portion of the XML or replace the "contents" tag with empty string. Which approach is better in your opinion? XSLT or regex?

Comment: Using RegEx to filter XML files is considered to be bad-practice, so XSLT is the language of choice. If you need to filter the base64 content of the `<contents>` element with RegEx, you will have to use XSLT-2.0 or higher (look for the `fn:replace` function), but XSLT-2.0 is not part of the .Net framework and so you'd need an external XSLT-2.0 or XSLT-3.0 processor in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude the `contents` element, you need to use:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::contents)]"/>
```

instead of your:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::company)]"/>
```

In addition, since `contents` is child of `book`, you need to do this in a template matching the `book` element, not the `/` root node. And you also want to copy the parent `book` and its attributes - so that would be:

```
<xsl:template match="book">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *[not(self::contents)]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

or - if you need to remove the source namespace (which your example does not have?):

```
<xsl:template match="book">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *[not(self::contents)]"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: thanks, "company" was typo. it should have been "contents".

Answer (score -3):

Using Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<XElement> contents = doc.Descendants("contents").ToList();
            for (int i = contents.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                contents[i].Remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```